# No performance improvement by using AsyncTask inside instantiateItem (PagerAdapter)

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-viewpager, android-image, android-bitmap

I am using a `ViewPager` to display my images full screen. Basically you click the image thumbnail and a new activity starts which has the image full screen. The images are displayed by creating bitmaps from the file path of the system. Since the bitmap processing is resource intensive i have moved it inside an `AsyncTask` thread. However, despite doing this I see no improvement in performance.

My Activity transition still delayed and i do not see any progress dialog.

```
public class ZoomImageAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private List<String> imagePathData = new ArrayList<String>();
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private View itemView;
private TouchImageView imageView;
private ViewGroup container;


public ZoomImageAdapter(Context context, List<String> data){
    this.mContext = context;
    this.imagePathData = data;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.imagePathData.size();
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    this.container = container;      

    BitmapHandling bitmapHandling = new BitmapHandling();
    bitmapHandling.execute(imagePathData.get(position));

    View result = null;

    try {
        result = bitmapHandling.get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return result;
}

private class BitmapHandling extends AsyncTask<String, View, View>{

    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    String path;
    Bitmap bitmap;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(mContext,"","");
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_zoomimage, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected View doInBackground(String... params) {

        path = params[0];
        bitmap = Utility.compressBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path), 720);

        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(View result){
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        imageView = (TouchImageView) result.findViewById(R.id.iv_zoomImage);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(result, 0);
    }
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    ((ViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code wouldn't even compile, just look at the `doInBackground()` method.:)

Anyway - it does not work because you call `AsyncTask.get()` which is blocking. It waits for the background task to be complete and the return its result.

You have to rather return something (probably custom view) from your `instantiateItem()` method right away and start the `BitmapHandling` task from within there.